# Python's equivalent of $this->$varName

Tags: php, python

In PHP I can do the following:

```
$myVar = 'name';

print $myClass->$myVar;
// Identical to $myClass->name
```

I wish to do this in Python but can't find out how

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In python, it's the getattr built-in function.

```
class Something( object ):
    def __init__( self ):
        self.a= 2
        self.b= 3

x= Something()
getattr( x, 'a' )
getattr( x, 'b' )
```

Answer (score 5):

You'll want to use the getattr builtin function.

```
myvar = 'name'

//both should produce the same results
value = obj.name
value = getattr(obj, myvar)
```